# Insert a duplicate copy of any record that meets certain criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry for this somewhat naive question but I am relatively new to SQL. Could someone help me write a SQL code (SQL Server 2014)?

I have a table “A” with 10 columns. Column 9 has any of these four values: “Test”, “Hold”, “Go”, or “Flag”

I would like to insert a duplicate copy of any record where column 9 has a value  = “Hold” or “Go” and change it to the value “Step 3”.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into t (col1, . . . col10)
    select col1, . . . col8, 'Step 3', col10
    from t
    where col9 in ('Hold', 'Go');
```

If one of the columns is generated automatically, then just leave it out:

```
insert into t (col2, . . . col10)
    select col2, . . . col8, 'Step 3', col10
    from t
    where col9 in ('Hold', 'Go');
```

Comment: How do you handle the Primary key index as I cannot duplicate it?

Comment: What columns are your primary key? What values do you want to use instead since you asked for a "duplicate copy"?

Comment: @SamSmith1986, if it's an `IDENTITY` column, just omit it from the column from the insert and select list and the value will be automatically generated.